# Inserting Multiple values into a single null columns using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've to Update a table which has two columns and 300 rows

In which One column is filled already and the second column is Null.

How to Update the Null column at once using a query.

What I've tried is

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Column_2 = (
        CASE column_2
            WHEN 'NULL'
                THEN 'Value1'
            WHEN 'NULL'
                THEN 'Value2'...
            WHEN 'NULL'
                THEN 'Value300'
            ELSE column_2
            END
        )
```

When i run this query, editor said (300 rows affected)

But when i look into the table, it's not updated

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are you actually trying to fill the first record you happen to find with the string 'Value1', the second with 'Value2' and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do what you want by enumerating the rows and then using the enumeration:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by column_1) as seqnum
      from tablename t
     )
update tablename
    set colum_2 = (case when seqnum = 1 then 'Value1'
                        when seqnum = 2 then 'Value2' 
                                           .
                                           .
                                           .
                        when seqnum = 300 then 'Value300'
                        else s_type 
                    end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Also SQL doesn't recognize 'NULL' as a string when you are referencing it. A true NULL value is called NULL without the single quotes.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET colum_2 = COALESCE('Value1','Value2','Value300',S_Type)
```